# django serializer queries db for forign key id

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-serializer

I serialize several objects using django serializer but problem is each serialize queries the foerign key's id from db, instead of just taking it from object e.g.

```
class QBAccount(CompanyModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

>>> from deretoapp.models import QBAccount
>>> import logging
>>> l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
>>> l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
>>> a = QBAccount.allobjects.all()[0]
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> serializers.serialize('python', [a])
(0.000) SELECT `deretoapp_company`.`id`, ... FROM `deretoapp_company` WHERE `deretoapp_company`.`id` = 45995613-adeb-488f-9556-d69e856abe5f ; args=(u'45995613-adeb-488f-9556-d69e856abe5f',)
[{'pk': u'3de881eb-8409-4089-8de8-6e24f7281f37', 'model': u'deretoapp.qbaccount', 'fields': {... 'company': u'45995613-adeb-488f-9556-d69e856abe5f' ....}}]
```

Is there a way to change this behavior without modifying django code? I know `a.company.id` will query company table (which should not happen in ideal world) but is there an option in serializer so that it does something like `a.company_id` which will not query the db

```
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying django python serializer so that it directly gets referenced object's id instead of getting it from db

```
from django.core.serializers.python import Serializer as PythonSerializer
from django.core.serializers.python import Deserializer

class Serializer(PythonSerializer):
    internal_use_only = False

    def handle_fk_field(self, obj, field): 
        if not self.use_natural_keys:
            # directly get the id
            self._current[field.name] = getattr(obj, field.attname)
            return

        return super(Serializer, self).handle_fk_field(obj, field)
```

I am not sure if it takes care of all `ForeighKey` usecase but it works for simple cases like `company = models.ForeignKey(Company)`

Also need to register serializer in settings.py

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = { 'python' : 'myapp.serializers.python' }
```

I also filed a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17602)  for this, which is now fixed in django trunk.
[see changset](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17439)

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize using [*Natural Keys*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys).

Essentially, this requires your to define a method called `natural_key` on the foreign key referenced model, that returns the fields you would rather have, in the place of the pk

From the documentation:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    birthdate = models.DateField()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('first_name', 'last_name'),)
```

and then set the parameter `use_natural_keys` to `True` during serialization.

Again, from the documentation:

```
>>> serializers.serialize('json', [book1, book2], indent=2, use_natural_keys=True)
```

Comment: this will not avoid the db query and I want `id i.e pk` not natural keys

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing to avoid the extra queries seems not very efficient either, but it does the trick:  add `select_related(...)` to your original queryset to load the related objects in the initial query.

For example:

```
a = QBAccount.allobjects.select_related('company').all()[0]
```